# How to CONCAT data with existing data in MySql using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to concat a single field with a variable in Mysql using codeigniter.

```
$this->db->set('my_field', 'my_field'.'My_variable', FALSE);
$this->db->where('my_other_field', 'test');
$this->db->update('my_table');
```

Comment: Any error you get from this script ?

Comment: No, it just updates field value with the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use . as concatenation for mysql you need to use `CONCAT` function

```
$this->db->set('my_field', "CONCAT(my_field,' ','".$your_variable."')", FALSE);
```